# Ubuntu on vmware ssh connection refused issue

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vmware

I have installed ubuntu server 16 on vmware. My desktop pc ip is 192.12.33.174 and ubuntu server ip is 192.12.8.57

I am connecting to ubuntu server via putty 22 port. And sometimes putty connection refused error occured. I can not ping to server. And I am logging in another machine that ip is 192.12.8.97 this machine ping is successful. But my desktop mechine(192.12.33.174) can not ping to server. After 15- 20  minutes later can ping.

Comment: How is the networking configured on the virtual machine? NAT, bridged, host-only?

Comment: vmware default network configuration used (NAT). I can not select bridge from vmware configurations. Bridge selec option does not exist.

Comment: Virtual machine configuration - Network adapter - Should present options for "Bridged", "NAT", "Host only", "Customs" etc. However, if the VM is configured for NAT, then is the 192.12.8.97 machine also a VM?

Comment: Yes 192.12.8.97 is a vm on same vmware

Comment: So what happens when you watch the machine booting and log into the console? Is the networking up? Can you ping the host from the VM?

Comment: Yes I can after reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Check the ssh service status:

```
service open-ssh status
```

If you don't have it, just install openssh-server

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

And restart the Virtual Machine (VM)

```
sudo reboot
```

And just connect again.

[Source for above answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrImjz_fARk)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** As videos do not contain any text that is searchable, pure video answers are not allowed here...  Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the video into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link to the video at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material... Извините.

Comment: Вот так хорошо?) Если что - простите мой английский) ::: that right?  sorry my English)

Comment: Ваш английский лучше, чем мой русский!  **;-)**  I know enough Russian to *get into trouble with the police* but not enough *to get out of trouble!*  **:D :D :D**

Comment: An edit *and an upvote!*  **;-)** (No, wasn't me who downvoted)